# What does 德法兼修 mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context

Another banner welcoming new students to Nankai University in the Law Building (I walk past these daily, so I'm hoping to practice reading them as I walk past each day):

[image: 励志勤学 德法兼修 祝新同学健康成长进步]

I transcribe this as:

> 励志勤学 德法兼修 祝新同学健康成长进步
>   <sub>Lìzhìqínxué défǎjiānxiū zhù xīntóngxué jiànkāng chéngzhǎng jìnbù</sub>

I believe the last part 祝新同学健康成长进步 translates directly: "wish ([祝](http://dict.cn/%E7%A5%9D)) new students ([新](http://dict.cn/%E6%96%B0)[同学](http://dict.cn/%E5%90%8C%E5%AD%A6)) health ([健康](http://dict.cn/%E5%81%A5%E5%BA%B7)), growth ([成长](http://dict.cn/%E6%88%90%E9%95%BF)) and progress ([进步](http://dict.cn/%E8%BF%9B%E6%AD%A5))".  The first part seems adequately translated using dict.cn; we have: [励志](http://dict.cn/%E5%8A%B1%E5%BF%97) = "pursue a goal with determination" and [勤学](http://dict.cn/%E5%8B%A4%E5%AD%A6) = "study diligently".

I don't understand the middle part 德法兼修 (défǎjiānxiū).

- [德法](http://dict.cn/%E5%BE%B7%E6%B3%95) is listed as "defa", and Google Translate translates it to "Germany and France".
- [兼修](http://dict.cn/%E5%85%BC%E4%BF%AE) is listed as "minor in", and Google Translate translates it to "minor".

I got nothing; neither of these is meaningful.

<sub>(If it helps, I noticed it was also mentioned in [a news article](http://newsweb.nuaa.edu.cn/2017/0510/c741a41730/page.htm) entitled 人文与社会科学学院举办“**德法兼修**，点赞青春”普法教育实践课暨玄武区法院庭审进校园活动.)</sub>

Comment: 德：品德 (morality)；法：法律知識 (knowledge about laws)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand every single character firstly,

```
德：道德（morality)
法：法制/法律（law）
兼：同时涉及/具有多方面（simultaneously/concurrently）
修：学习/培养（study）
```

So it could be literally translated as `study and improve both morality and legal knowledge`.

Comment: Somewhat similar to *leges sine moribus vanae*

Answer (score 1):

Split 德法兼修:

德 means 道德 virtue, morality;

法 = 法律 law;

兼 = 并，一起， and or together;

修 = 修行， study or major in the context;